# Can't use gcd function in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

what is wrong here I tried to use gcd function
but it give me this error
but when I used floor and sqrt functions from math it works without any errors

```
import math
from random import *
p=int(input("Enter p value"))
q=int(input("Enter q value"))
n=p*q
z=(p-1)*(q-1)
e=0
'''Select E Value'''
seed(1)
while(True):
    Random_Value=randint(2,n)
    if math.gcd(z,Random_Value)==1:
        e=Random_Value
        break
```

[image]

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't have `math.gcd`. It was added in 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `gcd` function from `fractions`:

```
import fractions
print fractions.gcd(3, 6)
```

As khelwood said, the `gcd` function was added to the `math` module in Python 3.5 ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd)).

Comment: Note that ``math.gcd(-3, -2) = 1`` and ``fractions.gcd(-3, -2) = -1`` (tested in Python 3.7.9).